# Auto increment field inside mysql database is incrementing with more than one

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am using the following code to insert values into my database, I have a id field which is Auto Increment, which I suppose should number each next value inserted incrementing it with one, in my case the id values are incrementing sometimes with more than one, for example the last id was 900 the next one will be 904, I would like to know if the following code is making this bug inside my database, this is happening for example if I choose an option on duplicate key where it should update only next time when I choose insert it is inserting and incrementing with few numbers, here is the code:

```
    $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ); 
    $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $stmt = $con->prepare( "Insert Into subscriptions ( curso_id, user_id ) 
    Values ('$cursoid', '$userid') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE curso_id = curso_id, user_id = user_id;"  );
    $stmt->execute();
```

With other words I am receiving gaps inside id Auto Increment row using this insert function. how I can solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you deleted any record on the table? If you did the auto increment field will still continue to increment base on the last inserted data which is deleted.

Example

Id        name
1          name 1
2          name  2
3          name 3        <- deleted

Then you will insert new data it will insert 4 in id not 3.

Id       name
1        name 1
2        name 2
4        name 4

Hope this helps.